# When does unresolved merge conflict happen?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've been digging through Visual Studio's settings and I found a default task list comment `UnresolvedMergeConflict` that has high priority status. Since the key word is written without spaces, I guess this is inserted automatically during some (merging?) process. I'd like to know when and how this message may be inserted, and if it's safe to delete it from that list.

Comment: There's no reason to assume that this is ever inserted automatically by a tool. The other comments are not necessarily. `TODO` is the only one I've ever seen a tool (wizard) generate; they don't often put `HACK` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking a source code configuration system (see eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) is used to keep track of source files (and other files) as a project progresses. When file versions are merged (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28revision_control%29) some changes can be automatically merged, but some changes cannot hence the conflict warning. Generally such conflicts occur when two different changes have been made to the same line (or adjacent lines) when both changes are compared to a common ancestor version of the file.

Comment: Which tool is it specifically that adds this comment from within Visual Studio? You're just providing general information here. You have to read more than just the title of the question.

Comment: @CodyGray did you read the whole question and my answer in full? The question does ask which specific tool generates the message, the question asks "*when and how this message may be inserted*". No one else gave any answer for 17 hours so I wrote an answer that was intended to help the questioner.

Comment: You've answered "what does 'unresolved merge conflict' mean?", not "when and how might this message be inserted?" I'm not criticizing your intentions, of course.